# Dask, how to elegantly assgin division names after map_partitions?

Tags: python, dask

Dask DataFrame Structure:

|                | column1| column2   | column3      | column4   |
| -------------- | ------ | --------- | ------------ | --------- |
| npartitions=58 |        |           |              |           |
|                | str    |  float    | float        | float     |
|                | ...    | ...       | ...          | ...       |
| ...            | ...    | ...       | ...          | ...       |
|                | ...    | ...       | ...          | ...       |
|                | ...    | ...       | ...          | ...       |
Dask Name: assign, 2378 tasks

```
# input
def function(one_partition):
    ......
    return float

result = ddf.map_partitions(function)
result.compute()
```

```
# output
0       0.103405
1       0.205377
2      -0.281792
...
56     0.103557
57     -0.228460
dtype: float64
```

`column1` is different for every partition, but inside any single partition, it has the same value. In other words, `column1` is partition-specific (each partition has its identical value).

index of `# output` series is also partition-specific.

I want the index of `# output` to have the partition-specific value same as `column1`.

I know there is a way to achieve this. Use `nunique().compute()` for `column1` and reassign the output index afterward.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how. Thanks for @github.com/ppoak

In the `function` passed into `map_partitions`, make its return type `pd.Series` instead of `float`, although it has only one index and one value.

The indexes for every returned series together compose the index of the output.

Besides, do not forget to assign the `meta` parameter in `compute()`